When ever I am using Jupyter notebook it is showing me error messages on the codes that are working on other computers, what can be the problem?
I tried this code
cars = pd.series(["BMW", "Toyota", "Honda"])

and it is giving me this error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 series = pd.Series(["BMW", "Toyota", "Honda"])

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'

I tried to create a series of cars and I was expecting to get the series if I enter cars

error and provided code don't match... [ask] and [mre]

The posted code has pd.series, but the code in the error message has pd.Series.  Please post the real code.

Use Series instead of series. example:
import pandas as pd
cars = pd.Series(["BMW", "Toyota", "Honda"])
print(cars)

Output
0       BMW
1    Toyota
2     Honda
dtype: object

